# Change Crystal Report Text Object Text at Run time

Tags: vb.net, object, text, crystal-reports, edit

I'm using a Crystal Report on my project. It's working very well but I just want to make it more flexible.
I have text objects with text in them. They are not bound since they are just additional information on my report. How can I make those text objects editable during runtime? Something like on mouse click, so the user can edit it like what I do in design? do I need to add a program in my project? I'm using vb.net 2010

I use this code to call my report

```
Dim sett As New DataSet1
Dim oRpt As New Accountability
Dim obj As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject
obj = oRpt.ReportDefinition.Sections("Section5").ReportObjects.Item("txtRel")
'Connection code, sql query here
Rpt.SetDataSource(dta)
frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt
frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
frmReport.Show()
```

the text object that I need to edit is not bound. Its created during design time

Answer (score 4):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim oRpt As New Accountability

    frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt
    frmReport.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub btnChangeText_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs) Handles btnChangeText.Click
    Dim oRpt As New Accountability
    ' Change the text of the TextObject you want to change here
    DirectCast(oRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("Text1"), TextObject).Text = "Your Text"
    DirectCast(oRpt.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects("Text2"), TextObject).Text = "Your Second Text"

    frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt
    frmReport.CrystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    frmReport.Show()
End Sub
```

This is what you need!

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what i need is that I Can edit it after the report has been loaded. I cannot fix the text since the user can input whatever he wants to put. Something like he can edit this report in design time.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim objText As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.TextObject =  
       Report.ReportDefinition.Sections(1).ReportObjects("txtDate")

objText.Text = frmList.txtCall.Text
```